# How init a new controller in prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I'm new in prestashop and I am trying to create a new page inside a module.

I created the controller and it view.

```php
<?php

class OpartDevisAskTypeClientModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

    public function initContent() {
        parent::initContent()
        $this->setTemplate('module:opartdevis/views/templates/front/ps17/askType.tpl');
      }

    public function setMedia($isNewTheme = false)
    {
        parent::setMedia();
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I try to acess to it "http://.../module/opartdevis/asktypeclient" I get this message:

```
Warning: include_once(.../modules/opartdevis/controllers/front/asktypeclient.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .../classes/Dispatcher.php on line 392

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '.../modules/opartdevis/controllers/front/asktypeclient.php' for inclusion (include_path='.../vendor/pear/pear_exception:.../vendor/pear/console_getopt:/.../vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/.../vendor/pear/archive_tar:.:/usr/local/php7.1/lib/php') in /.../classes/Dispatcher.php on line 392

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'opartdevisasktypeclientModuleFrontController' not found in /.../classes/controller/Controller.php:219 Stack trace: #0 /.../classes/Dispatcher.php(507): ControllerCore::getController('opartdevisaskty...') #1 /.../index.php(28): DispatcherCore->dispatch() #2 {main} thrown in /.../classes/controller/Controller.php on line 219
```

I don't really understand it, do I have to declare the controller somewhere else?

Thanks in advance

Malaury

Answer (score 0):

It is explained very well in the official documentation here, [DevDocs](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/)